# Set id in angular2 component

Tags: angular

I've created an angular2 component to host a Label together with input and validation messages. The template Looks like this:

```
<div class="form-group" [ngClass]="{'has-error':!formcontrol.valid && formcontrol.touched}">
    <label class="col-sm-2 control-label" >{{label}}</label>
    <div class="col-sm-6">
        <input class="form-control" type="text" [formControl]="formcontrol">
        <div *ngIf="formcontrol.hasError('required') && formcontrol.touched" class="alert alert-danger">muss ausgefüllt werden.</div>
        <div *ngIf="formcontrol.hasError('minlength') && formcontrol.touched" class="alert alert-danger">diese Eingabe ist zu kurz.</div>
        <div *ngIf="formcontrol.hasError('maxlength') && formcontrol.touched" class="alert alert-danger">diese Eingabe ist zu lang.</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

My component.ts:

```
import { Component, Input } from "@angular/core";

@Component({
    selector: "bs-ctrl-string",
    template: require("./bs-ctrl-string.component.html"),
})
export class BsCtrlStringComponent {
    @Input() label: string;
    @Input() formcontrol: any   
}
```

I use this component from other components like this:

```
<bs-ctrl-string [label]="'first name'" [formcontrol]="form.controls['firstname']"></bs-ctrl-string>
<bs-ctrl-string [label]="'last name'" [formcontrol]="form.controls['lastname']"></bs-ctrl-string>
```

My problem is: For end-to-end-tests I need to access the Input:

```
browser.FindElement(By.Id("firstname")).SendKeys("Sam");
```

Problem is: how do I set the id of the input field in my component from the hosting component? It would need to be something like this:

```
<bs-ctrl-string inputid="firstname" [label]="'first name'" [formcontrol]="form.controls['firstname']"></bs-ctrl-string>
<bs-ctrl-string inputid="lastname" [label]="'last name'" [formcontrol]="form.controls['lastname']"></bs-ctrl-string>
```

Comment: What's the problem with "It would need to be something like this:"?